# How to get an string representation from an NSDecimal without any formatting?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

For example, I have an NSDecimal myDecimal. Lets say it represents something like "-1234567.89"

**How can I get a clean string representation of that decimal without any beautification / formatting? No localization? Floating point symbol = . and rest only numbers from 0 to 9, and eventually an - if it is negative?** I need that string in strict technical manner. A number like 123456789876554432123456789.2231 should therefore not look like nice formatted "123,456,789,876,554,432,123,456,789.2231". You get the point right?
I don't want any formatting. I'm trying all day now to get that right but everything I find always has to do with formatting. So how'd you guys do that?

Comment: When you choose to use `.` character for separating integer and decimal parts, you use some formatting. For me an unformatted decimal would use `,` instead.

Comment: By default, the NSDecimalString() function does not add the thousands separator, so are you just having a problem with the decimal separator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a thing as a "clean" string representation independent of specifying the locale. As many Europeans would point out, 123.45 should be written as 123,45 (using , instead of . for the decimal location). `NSDecimalString()` (which can be found in  the [Foundation Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html)) takes, as a second parameter a locale specification. If some locale uses the format you desire, pass that locale as the second parameter (see the [Internationalization Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144) for more info on locales).

Alternatively, you can use an [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-9197), which will give you more controll over the string representation.

Answer (score 3):

For easy (localized) control use an NSNumberFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

```
float number = 12.345;
NSString* numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", number];
```

That will give you consistent formatting regardless of the user's current locale.

Comment: In his case, he's asking about an NSDecimal, not a standard floating point type.  However, he could extract the floating point value from the NSDecimal (by creating a temporary NSDecimalNumber and using its floatValue or doubleValue methods) and then use the format string you describe.